# How to resize the emulator in android studio 3.5

Tags: android-studio

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8r3n.png)I am struggling to resize the emulator as it is huge.

I have tried most of the tips that are on stackoverflow but without success. The posts are fixing old android studio versions.
When i am reducing size by pressing CTRL+UP the emulator is reducing is size but the phone screen is not fitting into the phone. See image please

Your help will be highly appreciated as I need android studio for my assignment.[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx2yb.png)

Comment: Please share more details like which version you are using , how big it it , screen resolution etc

Comment: I am using the latest android studio and gradle

Comment: Please add more details and screen shots of the issue that you are facing in order to facilitate other people solve your problem.

Answer (score 16):

I use hot keys `Ctrl + Arrow Up` to make emulator larger, `Ctrl + Arrow Down` to make emulator less.

Comment: i wonder why this is not marked as answer. worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

Just put the mouse cursor on one of the emulator corners until the resize arrow appear and then drag it in one of the directions, the size will change(like a normal window).

I just tested it and it works perfectly...

Comment: Dor, thank you for your prompt response. It is reducing the size of the emulator but the screen is not going into its place, into the phone. see picture

Comment: remove the skin.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Martin. Same thing, the screen of the emulator is becoming smaller and smaller and is going to the top left of the window

Answer (score 0):

At the end I managed to fix the emulator. I have uninstalled packet tracer. Do not know what was happening, but this cisco app was affecting android studio (emulator).

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same problem which I solved by uninstalling Cisco packet tracer, and by the way I had two versions of the tracer, one was 7.3.1 (this is the one I unistalled) and the other is 8.0 (and this is the one I kept), hope my answer helps someone.