# Shortcut for resizing AVD emulator window in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-studio-3.6

I installed `Android Studio 3.6.2` on recently bought dell latitude 5401 which runs on windows 10 pro.

The Android Virtual Device rendering on my laptop is too big for 14" screen, and too big to do any development.

What I am looking for is - shortcut to scale or resize `Android AVD` on `Android Studio`

[a screenshot of the emulator size on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwBjk.png) i already tried the ctrl+down key shortcut but it didn't work, any solutions ?

Comment: Already answered this particular query [How to resize the AVD emulator window in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29737499/10531665)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize the AVD emulator window in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737499/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-window-in-android-studio)

Comment: @SusobhanDas the versions of the Android studio in those answers are too old a lot had change from then to now

Answer (score 1):

You can resize emulator just by dragging on corner when resize arrow appears

Check this answer: on [Show emulator window in smaller size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59841981/10531665)

For Android Studio 3.5. solution was already posted Checkout : [How to resize the emulator in android studio 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58325077/10531665)

---

**Edit**
I think it can not be scaled below a certain threshold. But **Resizing by dragging** works in Android-Studio-3.6.2.

And because of your small laptop screen size, there is no information about additional scaling internally by copy-pasting code snippet.

You can rather go with **Genymotion** which is

1. lightweight
2. small-size and low on resource
3. can be resized according to preference

To use and run Android-Applications on **Genymotion**, run Genymotion and from Android-Studio install Genymotion plug-in then choose the Genymotion location.

When Genymotion is on, Android Studio detects it, you just need to hit **Play** button on Android studio to run Android-Application in Genymotion

Comment: I've already seen the answers posted and they didn't solve my problem because i tried dragging the  corners of the emulator without a result.

Comment: Actually it worked after i uninstalled Cisco packet tracer , now i only need to find out how it was affecting it to reinstall it again.